# Parse Cloud Function won't return response.success

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest, httpresponse, parse-cloud-code

My cloud function calls a web crawler I'm hosting and retrieves a string back, but I can't response.success the string back to my app if the string is long (it only works with short strings for some reason). Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("search", function(request, response){
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/',
        params: {
            keyword: request.params.searchTerm
        },
        success: function(httpResponse){
            // The httpResponse.text is received but for some reason
            // will not be returned with response.success
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        }, error: function(httpResponse){
            response.error(httpResponse);
        }
    });
});
```

I've been stuck on this problem for several days and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake, all that seems to be needed is the following when returning string to the app:

```
response.success(JSON.parse(httpResponse.text));
```

I'm not sure why this needs to be done with longer strings and it doesn't seem to matter with short strings but I'm sure there is a reason.

Comment: This actually causes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in <unknown file>:1 on some strings but not others. What does this mean?